Next.js deploy on Vercel - Error occurred prerendering page "/booking"
I am trying to deploy next.js on Vercel and while generating static pages, it throws the below error in logs vercel log error
this is my app structure directory: image structure
and this is the code of my /booking/page.tsx and /booking/layout.tsx
///booking/page.tsx
'use client';
import { useOrder } from "@/hooks/useOrder";
import { Step, StepLabel, Stepper } from "@mui/material";
import { GiHotMeal } from "react-icons/gi";
import Link from "next/link";
import Book from "./book";
import Addon from "./addon";
import Payment from "./payment";
import Finish from "./finish";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
const CurrentPage = ({ step, user }: { step: number, user: any }) => {
    switch (step) {
        case 0:
            return <Book user={user} />;
        case 1:
            return <Addon />;
        case 2:
            return <Payment />;
        case 3:
            return <Finish />;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
const steps = ['Book', 'Addon', 'Pay', 'Finish'];
const Page = () => {
    const { step } = useOrder();
    const { data: session, status } = useSession({
        required: true,
        onUnauthenticated() {
            redirect('/');
        },
    });
    return (
        <div className="bg-color-primaryBg flex flex-col">
            <div className="bg-white w-full shadow-md overflow-hidden flex items-center justify-center">
                <div className="min-w-[720px] max-w-[1280px] w-full h-[58px] flex flex-row px-6 justify-between items-center">
                    <Link href="/" className="flex">
                        <span className="font-semibold text-lg">Risol</span>
                        <GiHotMeal className="text-color-primary" />
                    </Link>
                    <div className="w-fit">
                        <Stepper
                            activeStep={step}
                            sx={{
                                '& .MuiStepConnector-line': {
                                    minWidth: '16px',
                                    margin: '0px 12px',
                                },
                                '& .MuiStepLabel-root .Mui-active': {
                                    color: '#0194f3', // circle color (ACTIVE)
                                },
                                '& .MuiStepLabel-label.Mui-active': {
                                    color: 'black', // Just text label (ACTIVE)
                                    fontWeight: 400,
                                },
                                '& .MuiStepLabel-root .Mui-completed': {
                                    color: '#0bc175', // circle color (COMPLETED)
                                },
                            }}>
                            {steps.map((label) => (
                                <Step key={label}>
                                    <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                                </Step>
                            ))}
                        </Stepper>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-6 mb-20 flex flex-col grow self-center">
                {session && <CurrentPage step={step} user={session} />}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Page;

/booking/layout.tsx
import { OrderProvider } from "@/hooks/useOrder";
export default function RootLayout({ children }: {children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return <OrderProvider>{children}</OrderProvider>
}

Here I created a multi-step form using useContext so I made this page client side.
I've tried to build and everything is normal like the following picture
but after I deployed it on Vercel, the error occurred, what should I do?
